# DHCP Client on Java, Can't send from IP 0.0.0.0

Tags: java, client, udp, ip, dhcp

I'm trying to create a DHCP Client using Java.
The client will send Discover, receive a Offer, send a Request, and receive an Ack.
However, when sending the discver and the request UDP DatagramPackets, I need to send them from the IP 0.0.0.0 port 68 because, the point of DHCP is is to receive a usable IP address from the DHCP Server.
However, If I bind my socket to a 0.0.0.0, according to the http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html Java Reference, the kernel will assign a IP address to the socket.

If I force set the IP address of my ethernet card to 0.0.0.0 via the

```
$ sudo ifconfig en0 0.0.0.0
```

and send my Packet; I receive a

```
java.io.IOException: Can't assign requested address
```

Exception.

Is there a way to send UDP packets from a 0.0.0.0 and set through `System.exec()` (if required) the IP address received from the DHCP server using Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that you won't be able to use this library to do DHCP. The library assumes that you won't want to use 0.0.0.0 as the sender address, even though DHCP specifies that you shouldn't put an ip address there. Just scanning the RFC, it seems to indicate that you "shouldn't fill out the sender field." Is it possible that it'll just be ignored? It may be that since DHCP is all broadcast, it won't matter and you can just fill out anything. Have you tried listening to DHCP requests on Wireshark or another packet sniffer to see if its really 0.0.0.0?

You may have to build your datagrams at a lower level.

I don't think it will matter how your own IP address is set if you're using DatagramSocket, because the library is going to change it if you try and assign 0.0.0.0.

Edit:
I scanned through parts of the dhclient source, and its huge and I don't understand it, but it looks like they are using shell scripts to configure the interfaces using ifconfig. So that may answer that part of the question. So you can just use your ifconfig to change your IP address as you are now.

Comment: Also, you're going to have to figure out a way to set your IP address from your java code since you will need to set the IP address for your DHCP client to work... Ooops, I missed that last part of your question. You might want to edit to make that stand out a bit better.

Comment: Yup I checked Wireshark and actual DHCP clients send packets from 0.0.0.0, while the client I created sends from the currently allocated address.... So Do you think I should Program with perhaps C?(To get to a lower level?)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Java will give you the flexibility you need, but I'm not sure what you need to do it. Rather than using DatagramSocket, you might be able to use Socket (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html). You'll have to do things that DatagramSockets do for you, like configuring it to do UDP. Unfortunately, I haven't done it in Java, only C, so I'm speculating. But I think that Java should be able to handle it.

Comment: This is kind of unrelated, but how would you send a packet from 0.0.0.0 in C? I'm trying a SOCK_RAW type, and created the IP and UDP header manually, but the kernel seems to modify the source IP address as it encounters the sendto() function. Any ideas or pointers for this problem?

Comment: I will admit that I haven't tried this, but I would assume that when you bind() you would specify 0.0.0.0 as your local addr. After you do that, sendto() is still using your IP addr?

Comment: See my note. Still not sure about the 0.0.0.0 issue. Have you tried setting your IP to 0.0.0.0 and then bind()ing to it in C?

Answer (score 0):

0.0.0.0 is the ip that represents the whole local network. You can't bind your network card to it, you can only send packets to it's broadcast ip 255.255.255.255

Comment: If for instance I would be coding in C, would a SOCK_RAW help me in any way?

Comment: @Heartinpiece probably a little late for you, but for the sake of anyone else who might be reading this - It's best to ask your modification as another question, since that would help guide other people looking for the answer to the same in C through search.